# Vagrant Drupal Development (VDD) Up Stalls

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm trying to figure out why vagrant is stalling. I installed VirtualBox 4.3.12 and Vagrant 1.6.2, and then grabbed Vagrant Drupal Development (VDD) environment. When trying to bring the machine up it will immediately stall, stuck on: default: Verifying Hyper-V is enabled...

```
==> Default: Verifying Hyper-V is enabled...
INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["c:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\
v1.0\\/powershell.EXE", "-NoProfile", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "&('c:\\Hash
iCorp\\Vagrant\\embedded\\gems\\gems\\vagrant-1.6.2\\plugins\\providers\\hyperv\
\scripts\\check_hyperv.ps1')", "-ErrorAction", "Stop"]
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stderr: The term 'ConvertTo-Json' is not recognized as the nam
e of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.6.2\plugins\providers\hype
rv\scripts\check_hyperv.ps1:10 char:38
+ Write-Output-Message $(ConvertTo-Json <<<<  $result)
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ConvertTo-Json:String) [], Comm
   andNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

DEBUG subprocess: stdout: ===Begin-Output===
```

===End-Output===

Comment: Please enable debug mode - see it here http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/debugging.html. The post the logs here.

Comment: I didn't copy the entire log. Just everything after Verifying Hyper-V is enabled.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is due to this error `stderr: The term 'ConvertTo-Json' is not recognized as the nam
e of a cmdlet`. Please check this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256706/running-powershell-script-in-c-sharp-converttojson-error

Comment: I saw that and I wondered that as well. Not sure what it all meant as it's a little beyound my scope of knowledge. I upgraded to powershell 3, downloaded windows admin tools and enabled Hyper-V to no avail. I don't know if they were even needed but I'm reaching for straws. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah! I simply added c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox to my PATH and all is well. I guess it was wanting to use vboxmanage command. I'm happy now.

Comment: It worked for me!